# How to set cordova on my PATH for NetBeans Cordova project on a Mac?

Tags: macos, cordova, netbeans-7

Using Netbeans 7.4 RC2. I was using the last beta and everything worked like a charm, but after upgrading, I started getting this error:

Netbeans cannot find cordova or git on your PATH. Please install cordova and git.

I know it's just that my my PATH needs to include cordova, since that was never required pre-RC, but I cannot figure out HOW!!!
The two examples I've run across are on Windows, but I am on a MacBook.

It's so aggravating that it's a one-line fix and I know nothing about how to fix it! Unless it is a NetBeans bug, but the Windows folks get it to work, so I assume I'm just naive.

Answer (score 0):

If you type in "`ps`" while at the UNIX prompt of the Terminal.app, you'll find out which shell you're running on.

In my case, I'm running "`tcsh`". Your path environment variable is found in your home directory:  "`~/.tcshrc`".

In some cases you might have "`bash`", where the path environment variable might be set in "`.bashrc`", "`.bash_profile`, "`.bash_login`" or "`.profile`".  [More information can be found in this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x?).

Comment: Yeah, I know how to change it for the most part, I just don't know WHAT to add to it, or why NetBeans isn't finding it.
This is what I have at the moment:
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of cordova? If you are using 3.1.0-X.X.X (not 3.0.X), that was released October 2, Cordova changed the version string returned on "cordova -v" command and NetBeans cannot handle it at the moment (because IDE consider it to be non-stable version of Cordova, like 3.0.0-rc1 and refuses to use it), thus saying "cordova not found".

Comment: It looks like I have 3.0.4, though the project I'm working on I specifically used 2.9.0, and I'm wondering if maybe this error is the reason I did that. Doesn't really matter though, because I can't even create a new Cordova project anymore without getting that error.

Comment: Try to run in terminal:
    "cordova -v"
and
    "git --version"

and paste output here. This is what NetBeans uses to detect Cordova and Git

Comment: cordova -v
3.0.4

git --version
git version 1.8.3.1

Comment: Thanks, in that case try to change the path to export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin:$PATH if it helps. I have Cordova in /usr/local/bin and it is symlink to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova

Comment: I have cordova and git symlinked in /usr/local/bin also, which is on my PATH, so I really don't get why it's not finding it.

Comment: But yeah, trying that doesn't work either. Pretty convinced it's a NetBeans bug at this point.

Answer (score 0):

try to add /usr/local/bin to your path. In both .bash_profile and .profile.
Also try to start netbeans from very same terminal, where both commands (git and cordova) works: $NETBEANS/bin/netbeans

Comment: This is the output I get with the NetBeans command:

$NETBEANS/bin/netbeans
-bash: /bin/netbeans: No such file or directory

Comment: sorry for not being precise. In terminal go to netbeans installation directory locate netbeans launch script, which is somewhere in bin subfolder and type "netbeans"

Comment: No worries.
This is the folder I found the script in, and it does open NetBeans:
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.4\ RC2.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked here https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236792
Please add output of following commands to NetBeans bugzilla.
which cordova
cat ~/.bash_profile
cat ~/.profile
Thanks